# get list of phone supported JSR

Tags: java-me, jsr

How can i get lis of phone JSR support on application ? is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only list I have found totally reliable is from searching http://www.forum.nokia.com/expert-search/?view=ds (the expert search lets you search for phones witch support specific JSR's) but this is obviously only Nokia phones :(

Comment: I think what you really want is something like J2ME Polish: http://http://www.j2mepolish.org/

Answer (score 2):

There are a few good online databases such as [Club Java](http://www.club-java.com/TastePhone/J2ME/MIDP_Benchmark.jsp) or Get Jar [(this is their N95 page for example)](http://devices.getjar.com/device/Nokia/N95).

Answer (score 0):

The authoritative source for JSRs is [The Java Community Process website](http://www.jcp.org/en/home/index). With the top left menu you can easily browse through the JSRs for the Java ME platform.

Comment: That's the list of all JSRs, but it doesn't tell you which handsets support them which is what I think he's looking for.

Comment: I can't fully understand the question so, given the tags and my interpretation of the summary, I gave the answer that better suited my point of view. I hope that our complementary answers can fulfill the question in its entirety.